# Is it possible to use Collections in App Widget before HoneyComb

Tags: android, widget

Hy!
I'm wonder if there is a way to use Collections (like StackView) in App Widget on version older than 3.0 (let say 2.2) with the compatibility pack or something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry. The Android Support package cannot modify the OS, and supporting Adapter-based app widgets is an OS-level change. You cannot use `StackView` and kin on Android 2.x devices.